# Distinguish normal function or closure in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, closures

I was confused with how to call a function which maybe a clousre When I learn JavaScript. I use Java before.

When I write a middleware such as for koa2, I write:

```
async function gzip(ctx, next) { }
```

If we need an option:

```
function gzipWithOption(option){
   return async function gzip(ctx, next) { }
}
```

or:

```
module.exports = options => {
  return async function gzip(ctx, next) { }
}
```

My confusion is, how koa2 or other compiler system to know if it should call:

```
theDarkFunc(param)
```

or:

```
theDarkFunc(option)(param)
```

How a programmer know that? Only by reading doc?

Comment: Normally the docs will indicate to you what the return value of something is. Otherwise if it's something that's written by you or someone else in your own codebase, you have to see whether the function is returning a value of some kind or returning a function

Comment: @francium yes, I can read doc, but how koa2 or other compiler system know that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience wit koa2 specifically or other node server frameworks, but determining whether the value returned by a function is another function or a regular value is quite doable at runtime in JavaScript.

For example, suppose you have a function called `f` that returns something but you don't know before hand. In that case we can check the value returned and perform an action accordingly.

```
f = () => { ... }

val = f()

// you don't know the type of val, so let's find out

if (val instanceof Function) {
  // val is a function, so you handle it in one way
} else {
  // val is not a function, so you handle it in another way
}
```

You can also use `typeof f()`, which will return `'function'` if the value returned by `f()` is a function (note that `typeof` returns a string, hence the quotation marks around the word 'function')

```
val = f()

typeof val === 'function'
typeof val !== 'function'
```

Comment: @hyyou2010, let me know if this still doesn't answer your question